# Transit visa in Paris

Tags: visas, transit, france, paperwork, cdg

I'm going from Morocco to USA via Paris and I will have to change terminals and pick up and check in my luggage between flights. Do I need a transit visa in Paris even if I have a valid US visa?

Comment: Are you Moroccan?

Answer (score 2):

You will enter France, and having a US visa doesn't exempt you from needing a Schengen visa.

So assuming you're Moroccan: yes, you need a short-stay (type C) visa from the French embassy. If the application form asks for the purpose of the trip, select transit.